# Making HTML <div> tag not take the entire length of the page

Tags: html

I am in the process of making my own website, and I am making it out of pure HTML. I encountered in the making of the page, as I will describe below.

Here's my code for reference :-

```
<head>
    <style>
        img {
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
      .sideDiv {
        border: 1px outset black;
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        width: 120;
        height: 400;
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      .mainDiv {
        border: 1px outset black;
        background-color: white;
        text-align: left;
        width: 400;
        height: 300;
      }
    </style>
    <a href="https://ayushbhatt.in"><img src="AyushLogo.png" alt="logo" height="9.2%" width="9.2%" style="float:left"></a>
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a><button>About Me</button></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a><button>Games</button></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a><button>My Blog</button></a> <br><br>
    <hr>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="sideDiv">
    
  </div>
  <div class="mainDiv">
  <p>Hi,<br>My name is Ayush Bhatt.<br><br>I love to code and remake old games. You can view some of my games by clicking on the 'Games' button on the top bar.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output looks like this :-
[image]

I wanted the  tag with the "mainDiv" properties to appear at the side of the one with the "sideDiv" properties, but it just doesn't want to.

PS : I want to use only HTML as long as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing about `<div>` tags is that they are known as ["block-level" elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), which in particular means that they always start on a new line and take up the full width available, regardless. With this in mind,
writing

```html
<div class="sideDiv"></div>
<div class="mainDiv">
...
</div>
```

should result in a div with class `sideDiv` and width as defined in the class, and then a new div with class `mainDiv` *started on a new line*, as block-level elements do by default, though note that this is simultaneously also because the div with class `sideDiv` takes up the remaining width on the page as a block-level element (though its *content* width is as described in the class, it being a block-level element is a bit like it "reserving" the rest of the width even though its content only uses the amount defined), so the next element (block level or inline) can *only* start on at least the next line.

If you want to circumvent this behavior, there are many ways to do it. One is by using an external tool like bootstrap, as pointed out by another answer, but my favorite is to simply use [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This can be done for your code in this way

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    <div class="sideDiv"></div>
    <div class="mainDiv">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

A method that directly overwrites the block-level property would be to set the style `display: inline-block;` for both divs, to prevent either from starting on a new line or taking up the whole available width by default. (Just one isn't enough, if you only set it on the first one, the second still starts on a new line by default, and if you only set it for the second one, the first still takes up all available width by default). However, this causes the element to be treated completely as an inline element besides the fact that block-level height and width can be applied, and can be strange/difficult to maneuver as a result. It is often easier to just use a flex box. Code for this would be

```html
<div class="sideDiv" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
<div class="mainDiv" style="display: inline-block;">
...
</div>
```

However, note that `<p>` is also a block-level element, so directly substituting in your original code in the `mainDiv` div would still cause it to skip a line before displaying. Again, it is usually easier, more modern, and better looking to just use a flex box.

Edit: Added the detail about block-level elements taking up all available width, and fixed the incorrect initial method that changed the display property to overwrite the block-level property by setting `display: inline;`. This can work, but it will ignore the heights and widths of the `<div>`s.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also include how the code would look if we used the "display: inline;" too? It might help someone looking for how to do it.

Comment: @InfinityMilestone My original answer wasn't completely correct for overwriting the `<div>`'s default block element property, since the first div would still have taken up the full width (independent of your specified content width). I just fixed it. There would be other things needed additionally if you wanted to make it look any good after doing it with inline-block though.

Comment: would you look at the coincidence! It worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

try using `bootstrap` , it deals with layout perfectly , here is an example :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      this is the left section
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      this is the right section
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more details check :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

NOTE : you will need to include `bootstrap` and `jQuery` libs , check for online tutorial to start using bootstrap

Comment: Is there any way to do it without JQuery? I want to use only HTML

Comment: bootstrap required jQuery to function properly , but that doesn't mean you need to use jQuery , you can do it with HTML only without need of javascript , but you just have to include it anyway